# How to append to a struct from another file?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to append to a struct from another file. I can do so, and it works in one file, but when I try to connect the second, it doesn't work.

I am trying to implement a checkout feature, and right now, I need to at least be able to append items to the cart.

## `currentOrderLogic.swift`

```
struct Cart: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var product_name: String
    var product_cost: String
    
}

public struct CurrentOrder: View {
    @State var items = [Cart]()
    func addObject(product_name: String, product_cost: String) {
        items.append(Cart(product_name: product_name, product_cost: product_cost))
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Current Order".uppercased()).font(.system(size: 30))
                    .frame(height:50)
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    HStack{
                        Text(item.product_name)
                        Text(item.product_cost)
                        }
                    }
                Spacer()
                Button("Charge $0.00") {
                    addObject(product_name: "Aooke", product_cost: "6")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the button, it is added and shown in the list.

Now, I am trying to have items that they can click, and when it is clicked, the item is added to the current order.

## `homeMenu.swift`

```
struct homeMenuObject: View {
    @State var posts: [Post] = []
    
    let date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(date, style: .date)
                Text(date, style: .time)
            }
            WrappingHStack(posts, id: \.self){ item in
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image("Logo").resizable().frame(width: 110, height: 55)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.title)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text((item.body).uppercased())
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }.frame(width: 110, height: 140).background(Color.white).onTapGesture {
                    CurrentOrder().addObject(product_name: "Aooke", product_cost: "6")
                }
            }.onAppear {
                Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                    self.posts =  posts
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

But when `CurrentOrder().addObject(product_name: "Aooke", product_cost: "6")` is called, nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Comment: First of all please get used to the naming convention that variable names are *lowerCamelCase* and struct and class names are *UpperCamelCase*. Either the views are related (one view is a descendant of the other) then use `@Binding` or `@EnvironmentObject` or use an `ObservableObject`, a view model.

Comment: You get it wrong: CurrentOrder() will create a new struct each time you call it. On tap gesture you should set a visibility indicator for a CurrentOrder that you present with posts as binding parameters (items declared as binding in CurrentOrder)

Answer (score 0):

Using ObservedObjects, I figured this out MYSELF.

currentOrderLogic.swift

```
public struct CurrentOrder: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var cartSystem : CartSystem
    
    public var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Current Order".uppercased()).font(.system(size: 30))
                    .frame(height:50)
                ForEach(cartSystem.items, id: \.self) { item in
                HStack{
                    Text(item.product_name)
                    Text(item.product_cost)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Charge $0.00") {
                    cartSystem.addObject(product_name: "Aooke", product_cost: "6")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

homeMenu.swift

```
struct homeMenuObject: View {
    @State var posts: [Post] = []
    
    @ObservedObject var cartSystem : CartSystem

    
    let date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(date, style: .date)
                Text(date, style: .time)
            }
            WrappingHStack(posts, id: \.self){ item in
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image("Logo").resizable().frame(width: 110, height: 55)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.title)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text((item.body).uppercased())
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                }.frame(width: 110, height: 140).background(Color.white).onTapGesture {
                    cartSystem.addObject(product_name: "Aooke", product_cost: "6")
                }
            }.onAppear {
                Api().getPosts { (posts) in
                    self.posts =  posts
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your main ContentView, I put this outside of the ContentView Structure,

```
class CartSystem: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Cart]()
    func addObject(product_name: String, product_cost: String) {
        self.items.append(Cart(product_name: product_name, product_cost: product_cost))
    }
struct Cart: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var product_name: String
    var product_cost: String
    }
}
```

Then I put this inside the ContentView struct

@StateObject var cartSystem : CartSystem = CartSystem()

Then, when I call the CurrentOrder struct and the HomeMenu struct, you pass this cartSystem variable in. This makes all of the CartSystem's the same, so you are not creating new instances of them and makes them connected.

Now i need to make the homeMenu objects pass their respective data into the order